# SSAS / MDX / ADOMD.NET - Retrieve last updated date from a cube

Tags: c#, ssas, mdx, adomd.net

I'm trying to retrieve the last updated date from a cube. I have a process that runs twice a day (eventually I would like it to be able to be executed at a click of a button but thats further down the line). I'm quite new to all of this.

So for now I'd just like to retrieve a datetime value through an MDX query of when that process was last run.

Here is my connection string:

```
public AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection("Data Source=BTN-SQL1;Initial Catalog=BTNTurboAnalysisServices;");
```

The process is called: Process SSAS

Then I've got this far, but I dont know what to write in my MDX query:

```
conn.Open();

    AdomdCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = @"
                      SELECT  
                      NON EMPTY   { [] } ON COLUMNS,
                                  { [] } ON ROWS
                      FROM        [Sales Analysis]
                      ";
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the schema to get that information.

I'm using ADODB objects, but you can find the corresponding ADOMD objects.

```
Set objRst = objConnection.OpenSchema(32, Array(strCatalog, vbNullString, strCube))
dtLast = objRs("LAST_DATA_UPDATE")
```

Sorry... wrong answer...

Try with the LASTSIBLING function:
    Select
    {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} On Columns,
    {[Date].[Fiscal].[Fiscal Year].&[2002].LASTSIBLING} On Rows
    From [Adventure Works]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually managed to solve it using the LastProcessed property of a cube, like so: cube.LastProcessed.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Comment: LastProcessed property sounds like a good solution for that sake. However, I did something else, I keep a log in a standard MS SQL DB table. Whenever I process my cube, I log the starting time and the ending time of the process externally. This gives me the added value of knowing the duration of the process each time it runs.